# Svg simple transformations

Tags: delphi, svg, transformation, algebra

I have a simple svg with 3 paths: red, blue and yellow.
I want to: scale all shapes (eg. 0.3) and rotate only the red + blue(eg.90 deg).
The rotation point should be the middle of red path.
After these operations I want the yellow shape to have the distance to the red path the original distance scaled by 0.3.

My attempt was:

1. compute the middle of the red path;
2. translate in the origin (0,0),by translated with (-redCenterPoint.x, - redCenterPoint.y)
3. Scale red path by 0.3
4. move back red path by translate(redCenterPoint.x, redCenterPoint.y)
5. repeat the same for blue and yellow by computing blueCenter, yellowCenter

**My question is:** How can I keep the original image structure but scaled by 0.3 and rotate by 90? - blue path to be in touch with red path and yellow to have original distance scaled by 0.3.

I saw that if I consider the redCenterPoint for all 3 shapes then the group looks the same as original but scaled, looks correct.
I want to know to do the same but with the first method.

[image]

svg file:

```
 <g
 inkscape:label="Layer 1"
 inkscape:groupmode="layer"
 id="layer1">
<path
   style="opacity:1;fill:#ff0000"
   d="m 146.98669,417.50473 561.36408,0 0,206.40686 -561.36408,0 z"
   id="red"
   inkscape:label="#table" />
<path
   style="opacity:1;fill:#0000ff"
   d="m 641.11218,339.32031 65.67491,0 0,82.87548 -65.67491,0 z"
   id="blue" />
<path
   style="opacity:1;fill:#ffff00"
   d="m 764.69525,515.63883 55.28473,-55.28473 46.43917,46.43918 -55.28473,55.28472 z"
   id="yellow"
   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
   inkscape:label="#yellow" />
```

code in delphi using Riversoft component for renderin SVG:

```
redBounds: TSVGRect;
redCenterPoint: TPointF;
redMatrix: TSVGMatrix

redBounds := (svgDoc.SVG.AllItems['red'] as TSVGGraphicElement).BoundsRect;

 redCenterPoint.x := bDiamond.Left + (bDiamond.Width) / 2;
 redCenterPoint.y := bDiamond.Top + (bDiamond.Height) / 2;

 redMatrix := CreateTranslateRSMatrix(-redCenterPoint.x, -redCenterPoint.y);

  redMatrix := RSMatrixMultiply(redMatrix,
    CreateRotationRSMatrix(TPoint(0,0), DegToRad(90)));

  redMatrix := RSMatrixMultiply(redMatrix,
    CreateScaleRSMatrix(0.3, 0.3));

  redMatrix := RSMatrixMultiply(redMatrix,
    CreateTranslateRSMatrix(redCenterPoint.x, redCenterPoint.y));

    (svgDoc.SVG.AllItems['red'] as TSVGGraphicElement)
      .Matrix := mainMatrix;
```

Comment: This is my question: I want after these transforms to keep the original image: blue path to be in touch with red path and yellow to have original distance scaled by 0.3. How can I control the position of blue path after aply transformation. I want to be the same image as the begging but scaled by 0.3.

Comment: I don't understand what you really want to do. Rotate? Scale? " keep the original image"? Could you show a picture of desired result?

Comment: Though I find it a bit difficult to understand what you want to achieve, it sounds like you want to group the blue and red and rotate that on it's own while scaling the overall group that holds all three paths together, but I can't be quite sure. It's particularly the bit about the yellow path I'm unsure about. As MBo - could you create a drawing.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is keeping the centre constant for each individual shape. That is not what you want to do. You want to keep the centre of the whole shape constant. That is what you are doing in your second attempt where you apply the red centre to all 3 shapes, which is why it looks better. You might want to choose a different centre, and there are various algorithms for doing that, or even leave the origin where it is (not bothering to move the centre at all). But you must apply the same centre, whatever you choose, to all shapes to achieve what you want, and that applies to rotation too (although in your case you only apply rotation to two of the shapes). The centre for rotation, though, does not have to be the same as the centre for scaling.

For the most effective operation for calculating your new centre in each case I thing I would use centre of gravity calculations, but just simple average of centres would work well too.